# How to get correct radiance values for IBL?

Tags: opengl, graphics, rendering, raytracing

I am implementing *Image Based Lighting* based on the paper [*Real Shading in Unreal Engine 4* by Brian Karis](http://blog.selfshadow.com/publications/s2013-shading-course/#course_content).

I got myself [some .hdr textures](http://www.hdrlabs.com/sibl/archive.html) to have high quality radiance values. But I don't trust them because I don't have any reliable reference values to compare them.

- The brightest value per channel of the texture *Grand Canyon C* (follow the link) is about 17 W*sr^-1*m^-2.
- The brightest value per channel of the texture *Ridgecrest Road* (follow the link) is about 9 W*sr^-1*m^-2.

Both textures show a clear sky and the sun is at about the same altitude. So I would expect comparable values.

[Wikipedia states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminance) that

> The sun has luminance of about 1.6×10^9 cd/m^2 at noon.

When I [convert this to radiance](http://www.unitconversion.org/unit_converter/luminance.html) (which should only be a rough approximation) the result is about 234.3. This seems to be quite far from the values I get from the textures.

1. **Are there any reference charts that hold radiance values of different light sources?**
2. **Can someone explain how I can get reliable radiance data?**
3. **Am I approaching this wrong?**